# Fixed cmake output directory

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm working on my first project using cmake, and for the most part it's been going well but I've run into one problem I can't figure out.

Let's say I have my `CMakeLists.txt` file located at `~/project/build`. I would like for the output from cmake (not the binaries, but the makefile/configuration files) to be independent of where I run cmake from.

As an example, if my terminal is sitting in the `~/project/build` directory, calling `cmake ~/project/build` creates the makefile and everything else within the `~/project/build` directory. This is the behaviour that I'd like. If I call `cmake ~/project/build` from anywhere else, it creates the makefile and everything else in whatever directory the terminal called the program from.

Is it possible to force cmake to generate its makefile and associated files in the same folder as the `CMakeLists.txt` file? I've taken a look through the documentation and I've had no problems figuring out how to change binary output directories, but I can't really find any mention of what I'm trying to do.

I realize this is a pretty minor annoyance (it's not that hard to move into my build folder before building the project) but I'm just wondering if it's possible and if there's some reason it wouldn't be advised.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `CMakeLists.txt` located in a build directory.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use 2 commands for this

1) cmake -B "Dest path(Any path in which u want to generate the output files)" -H"Source path(root CMakeLists.txt path)"

2) cmake --build "Dest path"