# Setting path for CMake files

Tags: cmake

Is there any way to specify where CMake should create its build files? I mean some kind of set function. I want to run CMake in root directory and get its files in /build directory.

Files I want to put to build directory:
CMakeFiles/
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeCache.txt
Makefile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed cmake output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213323/fixed-cmake-output-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the build directory using the `-B` flag. You can invoke cmake from anywhere by using the `-H` flag, which provides the source directory (with the CMakeLists.txt file).

```
cmake -H/path/to/source -B/path/to/build
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to achieve that by setting some variable on CMakeLists.txt?